# Samsung Galaxy Tab drivers

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, usb-debugging

Where can I find the Windows 7 drivers for the [Samsung Galaxy Tab](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SCH-I800BKAVZW)? Can't seem to find them on the samsung website.

http://www.samsung.com/us/support/supportDownloadCenter.do?prd_ia_cd=N0000407&prd_mdl_cd=SCH-I800&prd_mdl_name=SCH-I800

Ultimately, I need to deploy an application that I'm developing :-)

Answer (score 3):

I used the same drivers that I installed for my Samsung Galaxy S (Vibrant).

- [64 bit drivers](http://api.viglink.com/api/click?format=go&drKey=1359&loc=http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=728929&v=1&libid=1309577313905&out=http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/MOBILES/Samsung/Samsung-Galaxy-S-USB-Driver-for-Windows-x64.shtml&ref=http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CFQQFjAB&url=http%253A%252F%252Fforum.xda-developers.com%252Fshowthread.php%253Ft%253D728929&rct=j&q=samsung%2520galaxy%2520tab%2520usb%2520drivers&ei=K5AOTvP_MfHCsQLBzoj9CQ&usg=AFQjCNEr9dzPkNQSKfxanG-YZXxQrEtxMw&sig2=9irG4__dvVAyG-qviQ62XQ&title=%5BDrivers%5D%20MS%20Windows%20x86%20and%20x64%20USB%20Drivers%20for%20Samsung%20Galaxy%20S%20-%20xda-developers&txt=http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/MOB...dows-x64.shtml)
- [32 bit drivers](http://api.viglink.com/api/click?format=go&drKey=1359&loc=http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=728929&v=1&libid=1309577313905&out=http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/MOBILES/Samsung/Samsung-Galaxy-S-USB-Driver-for-Windows-x86.shtml&ref=http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CFQQFjAB&url=http%253A%252F%252Fforum.xda-developers.com%252Fshowthread.php%253Ft%253D728929&rct=j&q=samsung%2520galaxy%2520tab%2520usb%2520drivers&ei=K5AOTvP_MfHCsQLBzoj9CQ&usg=AFQjCNEr9dzPkNQSKfxanG-YZXxQrEtxMw&sig2=9irG4__dvVAyG-qviQ62XQ&title=%5BDrivers%5D%20MS%20Windows%20x86%20and%20x64%20USB%20Drivers%20for%20Samsung%20Galaxy%20S%20-%20xda-developers&txt=http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/MOB...dows-x86.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

Just download [Samsung Kies](http://www.samsung.com/in/support/mobilesoftwaremanual/mobilesoftwaremanual.do?page=MOBILE.SOFTWARE.MANUAL) and you're good to go!. All the mobile USB `drivers` come inbuilt along with `Kies`.

Answer (score 0):

The driver for Samsung Galaxy flagship are all the same, no need a specific driver type for a certain Samsung Galaxy device. Because Samsung has made it simple. You can directly head to the [Samsung Developers official website](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows) to download the driver for your device from this page and learn to install the driver from [this page](https://www.droiddrivers.com/2018/02/samsung-usb-drivers-all-usb-models.html).

Once you have finished installing the driver then you may be able to transfer files between your Samsung Android device to Windows and installing the stock ROM manually.